# Url change event in specific controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

How can i detect url change in specific angular controller?
This is mine for example:

```
 static $inject: Array<string> = ['$scope', 'common' ];
    constructor(public scope: any, public common: app.core.Common) {
       -> scope.on ? will work? 
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: which router are u using? And what do you want to achieve, would be interesting

Comment: function initRouter($locationProvider: angular.ILocationProvider,
                        $urlRouterProvider: angular.ui.IUrlRouterProvider,
                        $stateProvider: angular.ui.IStateProvider) {